# Ruby Read X509 Certificate Encrypted Private Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, x509certificate, public-key-encryption, x509

In my Ruby on Rails project I'm trying to read from a pem file "my_cert.pem" that has a "encrypted private key". It looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_LONG_STRING
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERTIFICATE_CONTENT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Calling `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("my_cert.pem"))` is throwing `eval error: nested asn1 error`.

Is there a nice way to get the private key, i.e. `ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_LONG_STRING` without brutally parsing the string?

Comment: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-Loading+an+Encrypted+Key